# npm broken inside Docker container

Tags: docker, npm, docker-compose, dockerfile

So, I updated npm inside docker container and since I have node version 6.9.4, npm is broken. Any npm commands will throw this error.

```
client     | module.js:471
client     |     throw err;
client     |     ^
client     |
client     | Error: Cannot find module 'process-nextick-args'
client     |     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
client     |     at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
client     |     at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
client     |     at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
client     |     at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:26:23)
client     |     at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
client     |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
client     |     at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
client     |     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
client     |     at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
```

and I would like to downgrade npm to 3.10.10.
Is there any way to do this without recreating the container?
I'm using docker-compose.

Comment: You can just do `npm upgrade -g npm@3.10.0`.

Comment: It doesn't work because npm is broken, so any npm command wouldn't work

Comment: Oh yes, of course. FWIW we eventually got so sick of NPM not working inside Docker that we switched to Yarn, and changed our base CI image to explicitly uninstall NPM !

Comment: What is the Dockerfile? What commands are being used to build and run the container? Being able to reproduce this issue would give a greater chance someone could answer it. Also, npm  3.10.10 is provided by Node 6.9.x. What do you mean by "it is broken" and you want to downgrade to  3.10.10? It should already be 3.10.10.

Comment: @AndyShinn I agree with you. I stupidly updated npm inside the docker container when Dockerfile has FROM:node6.9.4 so now I'm trying to get npm downgraded....

Comment: In that case, couldn't you just rebuild the image to get back to the npm version that came with `node:6.9.4`? Unfortunately, there isn't enough information here for me to really test or answer the question.

Comment: @AndyShinn Yeah, I think that will do it, I just didn't want to try that because I was afraid I was going to mess with the container.

Comment: Generally, you should strive to make the container reproducible. You should try to avoid making manual edits inside of it and use the shell / `docker exec` more for debugging. This way, in the future when you run into issues like this, you cam just rebuild or restart a new container to get back to a known working configuration.